# Prevents the 'XYZ binder is null' error message in LogCat

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-binder

Please READ FULLY and understand my question first as I'll be happy triggering the downvote button!

The question is really a LogCat-cosmetic. I don't have any crashes or actual problem with Bluetooth. I do get the "Bluetooth binder is null" LogCat message. There are many post and questions on how to use Bluetooth on the Android emulator. I know all of that, that is not the problem. What I'd like is simply to get rid of the LogCat error message. Right now I have a simple condition for determining I'm running on the emulator:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-kernel/M4SjXulUeUo

`boolean isEmulator = "goldfish".equals(Build.HARDWARE);`

This is not that great, if the kernel ( see link above ) of the emulator was to change or else the condition wouldn't be right anymore. So I though maybe there is a fancy Java way of determining presence or absence of a library or function within a library so I don't get the message on executing such:

`boolean isBluetoothAvailable = TTLBluetoothService.isBluetoothAvailable();`

Comment: I know the answer but I don't want to be downvoted. I don't like being threatened.

Comment: If it's relevant I won't. If it's about Bluetooth itself, well it's a good thing you didn't answer!